# What does IP_NETWORK and IP_DEVICE in the Decouple Python library mean?

Tags: python-3.x, decoupling

I was reading through the `Decouple` Python library, but I don't understand what the following code does-

```
IP_NETWORK = config("IP_NETWORK")
IP_DEVICE = config("IP_DEVICE")
```

I know that, there has to be a `.env` file setup, where the `IP_NETWORK` and `IP_DEVICE` have to be declared. But I'm not sure how this module works.
Also, how do I find the `IP_NETWORK` and the `IP_DEVICE` ?

I'm not too sure what I'm talking about and may not make sense, but any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: If someone can explain the working and usage of Python decouple library, this would help me and others. I'm setting a bounty for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

**[Python Decouple library](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/):** Strict separation of settings from code

Install:

```
pip install python-decouple
```

This library comes handy in separating your settings parameters from your source code. it’s always a good idea to keep your `secret key, database url, password etc...` in a separate place `(environment file - .ini/.env file)` and not in your source code git repository for security reasons.

It also comes handy if you want to have different project settings on different environment (e.g - You might want debug mode on for your development environment but not on production.)

**How do we decide whether parameter should go inside your source code git repository or environment file ?**

It's simple trick - Parameters related to  `project settings` goes straight to the source code and parameters related to `instance settings` goes to an environment file.

Below first 2 are `project settings` the last 3 are `instance settings`.

- Locale and i18n;
- Middlewares and Installed Apps;
- Resource handles to the database, Memcached, and other backing services;
- Credentials to external services such as Amazon S3 or Twitter;
- Per-deploy values such as the canonical hostname for the instance.

**Let's understand how to use it with Django(python framework).**

First create a file named `.env or .ini` in the root of your project and say below is the content of that file.

```
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=ARANDOMSECRETKEY
DB_NAME=Test
DB_USER=Test
DB_PASSWORD=some_strong_password
```

Now let's see how we can use it with Django. Sample snippet of `settings.py`

```
# other import statement..
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        # other parameters
    }
}

# remaining code.
```

Hope this answer your question.