# Python detect new connection to wifi

Tags: python, pip, decoupling

I saw a tutorial on YouTube(I can't link it because I can't find it anymore),
So the code is supposed to detect devices that are connected to my Internet/Router, I don't understand a lot about how his(The person who made the tutorial) code works

I also got this error in my console:

[image]

> File "c:/Users/j/Desktop/Connection-Detection.py", line 6, in 
> IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
> File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 199, in **call**
> return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 83, in **call**
> return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 68, in get
> raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
> decouple.UndefinedValueError: IP_NETWORK not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
> PS C:\Users\j\Desktop\python\login>

That's "Detection.py"

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
IP_DEVICE = config('IP_DEVICE')

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', IP_NETWORK],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline
    if not line:
        break
    connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

    if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
        subprocess.Popen(['say', 'Someone connected to network'])
```

Comment: you haven't defined the environment variable `IP_NETWORK`. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159573/what-does-ip-network-and-ip-device-in-the-decouple-python-library-mean

Comment: Do I just define them as normal variables like "var IP_NETWORK = '' "

And as I watched a tutorial, I don't think I know what to define them with, imma go google them real quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an environment variable in same directory as the `Detection.py` file.

**Steps**

1. Install python-decouple - `pip install python-decouple`.
2. Create a file called `.env`
3. Open the `.env` file and paste the following into it.

```
IP_NETWORK=YOUR_IP_NETWORK
IP_DEVICE=YOUR_IP_DEVICE
```

Replace `YOUR_IP_NETWORK` and `YOUR_IP_DEVICE` with your `IP_NETWORK and IP_DEVICE`

Comment: Thank you! I used to use .env in Node but I thought it wasn't a think in Python, I guess my understanding of that is wrong now.